# Condition in constructor javavascript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, conditional-statements, angle

I want to add condition in constructor for angle `if(angle>360){ angle=0; }` how to do?

```
PLAYER[i] = {
    color: "#fff",
    x: 220*i,
    y: 270,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    angle: 180
};
```

each time to use such a condition, takes a lot of space.

Comment: There's no constructor function in your question.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a handy box to the right titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. :-) As is the information available from the **[?]** button on the toolbar that was above the question text area. There's also a preview area underneath that's worth checking so you can see how your post will look and deal with any formatting issues, etc., before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a constructor -- just initialization of an object.  But nevermind that. Use the ternary operator: `angle: (angle > 360 ? 0 : angle)`

Comment: +1, I think you got to the heart of it.

Comment: Or just `+(angle <= 360) && angle`, if one has some ternaryfobia. )

Comment: Interesting syntax.  Haven't seen anyone do it like that before!  Was that a "for fun" solution or do people really do that in order to avoid a ternary operation?  That seems much less readable to me, but I'm curious if people are actually using it.